# C# delete registry key access denied

Tags: c#, registry

I am attempting to delete the USBSTOR registry key with the following code under an administrator command prompt.

```
void DeleteRegistryKeys()
{
    string keyOne = @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\";
    using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(keyOne, true))
    {
        if(key != null)
        {
            key.DeleteSubKeyTree("USB");
            key.DeleteSubKeyTree("USBSTOR");
        }

    }
}
```

I am getting a System.Security.SecurityException: Requested Registry Access is not allowed. Does anyone know a work around for this?

I attempted to run as admin but that does not work. 
I have added an app.manifest file that has

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

But that does not seem to help the program run either.

Comment: do you need the trailing `"\"` in the `keyone` variable

Comment: There error is the same with or without the trailing \

Comment: have you got UAC turned on in your system? what i mean does your code really receive admin rights? you can check it by [IsInRole](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46ks97y7.aspx) method

Comment: Yes I run a check prior to calling the above to make sure I am in role admin

Answer (score 0):

In my case, firstly I just added app.manifest file in project folder but it failed .

Then I setup app.manifest file in Project > Properties > Application > Resources > Icon and manifest > Manifest (VS 2017).  And It works.